# RegEx to match all occurrences of a character *after* the first occurrence?

Tags: objective-c, regex

For instance if I am trying to match 'w's in the input string

> edward woodward

the two 'w's in the second word should be matched, not the one in the first word.

I have an inkling the solution might involve 'negative lookbehind' but just can't get any working solution.

(I am working with Objective C and the regex replace methods on `NSMutableString` but I would also be happy to hear about solutions for any regex implementation.)

Comment: Think you actually need a "positive" lookbehind

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you'd need not just lookbehind (which some regex flavors don't support at all) but infinite repetition inside the lookbehind assertion (which only very few flavors support, like .NET for example).

Therefore, the .NET- or JGSoft-compatible regex

```
(?<=w.*)w
```

won't work in Objective C, Python, Java, etc.

So you need to do it in several steps: First find the string after the first `w`:

```
(?<=w).*
```

(if you have lookbehind support at all), then take the match and search for `w` inside that.

If lookbehind isn't supported, then search for `w(.*)` and apply the following search to the contents of the capturing group 1 (`$1`).

Comment: Great answer Tim, I conclude RegExes are not the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 5):

To replace every `N`-th `"w"` (where `N > 1`) with an `"X"` for example, you could search for the pattern:

```
(?<=w)(.*?)w
```

and replace it with:

```
$1X
```