# Replace element in string after first occurrence

Tags: regex, r, string

I wish to replace all `2`'s in a string after the first occurrence of a `2`, ideally using `regex` in base `R`.  This seems like it must be a duplicate, but I cannot locate the answer.

Here is an example:

```
my.data <- read.table(text='
                         my.string
                         .1.222.2.2
                         ..1..1..2.
                         1.1.2.2...
                         .222.232..
                         ..1..1....
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.data

desired.result <- read.table(text='
                         my.string
                         .1.2......
                         ..1..1..2.
                         1.1.2.....
                         .2....3...
                         ..1..1....
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
desired.result

my.last.2 <- c(4, 9, 5, 2, NA)
my.last.2
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: can you post an example of the desired output ?

Comment: @PedroLobito I believe his `desired.result` object is the desired output.

Comment: A variation on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5908655/324364) works I think.

Comment: @Gregor missed that, thanks!

Comment: I'm a little torn on whether to call this a duplicate of the question I linked to above. The question statement is basically identical, but the implementation needed some very slight tweaking to be R-specific.

Comment: I think you should leave it as is. That question includes a replacement of an ordinal position, where as this one just strips all trailing 2's. Same constructs, but different result's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to match your desired output:

```
> gsub(pattern = "(?<=2)(.*?)2",
       replacement = "\\1\\.",
       x = my.data$my.string,
       perl = TRUE)
[1] ".1.2......" "..1..1..2." "1.1.2....." ".2....3..." "..1..1...."
```

This is literally a directly modification from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5908655/324364) answer to a very similar question to make it R specific. I'll be honest, I don't quite understand this regex, so use (and up-vote) with caution.

Comment: Really don't understand what `*?` means -- I would expect `(.*)` to work if `(.*?)` does...

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't really either...about to edit to add a warning about my ignorance.

Comment: From [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mR5bH0/1), the difference appears to be "as few times as possible, expanding as needed" (`.*?`) vs. "as many times as possible, giving back as needed" (`.*`)... not that I fully understand that either

Comment: This works great, although it doesn't really jump out at you as to why. At the end of a match is a (?<=2)(.*?)`2`, at the beginning of the next attempt, there is a `(?<=2)`(.*?)2. It's seamless with no break in continuity.

Comment: Just found a little footnote of my favorite [regex cheat sheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) which mentions "Add `?` to a quantifier to make it ungreedy"

Answer (score 2):

This works, but is probably inefficient:

```
with(my.data, gsub("@", "2", gsub("2", ".", sub("2", "@", my.string))))
# [1] ".1.2......" "..1..1..2." "1.1.2....." ".2....3..." "..1..1...."
```

Approach: Use `sub` to only match the first occurrence and change it to `@` (or some other placeholder character which doesn't show up elsewhere in `my.string`, then use `gsub` to replace all remaining `2`s, then `gsub` `@` back into `2`.

Comment: @sin thanks. I think joran's is the way to go, since it's done in one shot... I'm leaving this here for its transparency, since I think it's pretty obvious how it works

Comment: I can't believe I was fooled by this regex. After staring at it a while `(?<=2)(.*?)2` it's clear that the end of the match is after the `2` so on the next match at least the lookbehind  `(?<=2)` is satisfied..